# Don't match if previous match contains a character

Tags: python, regex

Considering this piece of code from CFEngine:

```
"test"
  slist => { "this",
             "that" },

"test2" 
  slist => { "another,
             "another" 
           },

"test3" 
   string => "This one";

"test4" 
  slist => { "finally", 
              "this" }
```

I want a a code in Python that will get the identifiers ( "test1", "test2", etc.) and the content of what is between `{}`.

I came with this:

`re.findall(r'^\s*?\"(.*?)\".*?\{(.*?)\}.*?',filestring,re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)`

Which works fine, except that it ends up getting `'finally'.'this'` as a match for `"test3"`, and not for `"test4"`.

I tried to work a bit with loosbehind, this way:

`re.findall(r'^\s*?\"(.*?)\".*?\{(?!<.*?\".*?)(.*?)\}.*?',filestring,re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)`

hoping that `(?!<.*?\".*?)` would exclude matches that had a quote character before, but it didn't work and I kept having the same results.

Could anyone help me to achieve this? I know I could do other tests, such as testing if next line has `slist`, for example, but I want to avoid it because sometimes the code has comments, as in

```
"test4"
# some comment
slist => { "something"}
```

The only thing that I am sure would work with matching identifiers to their content is excluding results that had another assignment without `{}`. Therefore I am thinking about using the `"` sign to exclude matches, but it is not working the way I thought it would.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Comment: It looks like a case for some custom parser. [`(?m)^"([^"]+)"(?:\n#.*)*\s*.*?=>[^\w"]*(?:{(?=.*}))?(.*?)[^\w"]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/qFlivd/2) looks too fragile and cumbersome already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `^\s*?\"(.*?)\".*?(?:".*?"|\{(.*?)\})`

This matches the text between the first set of `""` then looks for either something between `""` or `{}` and if it's between `{}` captures it.

You will then need to check if the second capture group is set or not in your code.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit to make it work (see my own answer), but your answer was the one that led me to it, so creds where creds are due. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```
r'(?s)^("[^"]+").*?=> ("[^"]*"|{[^}]*})'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6EmQkY/2)

- `(?s)`: Enables DOTALL modifier.
- `("[^"]+")`: Matches and captures first quoted string
- `("[^"]*"|{[^}]*})`: Match 2nd group that can be a quoted string or `{...}`

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question to stress the fact that the code might have newlines between the content. Therefore your suggestion wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, with the help of both @anubhava and @JGNI:

```
re.findall(r'(?s)^\s*?\"(.*?)\".*?=> .*?(\".*?\"|\{.*?\})',filestring,re.MULTILINE)
```

This way I catch also stuff that I don't want, but it is easy to discard it.

Comment: `.*?` is lot more deficient than `[^"]*` or `[^}]*`

Comment: Then you have some other data not shown because my demo link shows all the 5 expected matches. Isn't it?